# Fabric hosts in combination with passwords and key_filename

Tags: python, fabric

Using Fabric version [1.9.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fabric/1.9.0). I have two users `root` and `abc`. `root` user requires ssh key and the other user require password to login on the same host:

```
from fabric.api import *

def production():
    env.hosts = ['root@host', 'abc@host']
    env.passwords = {'abc@host': 'pass'}
    env.key_filename = 'key.pem' # for root user


@hosts('root@host')
def test():
    run('id') # works

@hosts('abc@host')
def test2():
    # env.key_filename = [] # tried this no luck
    # env.no_keys = True # tried this no luck
    # env.use_ssh_config = False # tried this no luck
    run('id') # <------- asks password for user abc, why?
```

After executing `fab production test test2`, The `test2` is asking password for user `abc` shouldn't it be looking in `env.passwords`?

Comment: The documentation recommends the use of SSH Keys. ``env.password`` and ``env.passwords`` are used as in-memory cache(s) for convenience. I'm not sure they are meant to be abused in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the passwords via enviroment dict you have to specify the full host string *including the port number*. In your case: `env.passwords = {'abc@host:22': 'pass'}`